# Specify log-in in GMail URL

Tags: url, gmail

Part of an app I'm working on creates links to messages in GMail using their message ID:

```
"https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/" + encodeURIComponent(`rfc822msgid:${interaction.messageId.replace(/(^<|>$)/g, "")}`)
```

Simple enough.

The problem comes when a user has multiple Google accounts, and the message they're opening does not belong to the currently logged in one: The link should open a search with only one result, if the user isn't logged in to the correct account, no message is displayed.

**Is there any way to specify which email address to open the message with in the URL?**

Something along the lines of https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?user=helloworld@gmail.com#search/rfc822msgid:ABC@mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer over on [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18959).

You can use the query string parameter `authuser` to specify an account to use with the URL:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=user@gmail.com

or (using the URL from my question):

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?authuser=helloworld@gmail.com#search/rfc822msgid:ABC@mail.gmail.com